# create value to a model from another model's method

Tags: python, django, model

I'm trying to create a new table (`Payslip model`) that will contain the computed salary on an employee in a cutoff.

I want `Payslip.salary` to get value from  `Employee.compute_pay()`
Given the example in the url link above, what should my `views.py` look like?

Is this the best approach to this kind of process? or Is there any library that can help with what I want to do here?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs8CC.jpg

## model.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    rate = models.IntegerField()
    absent = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):    
        return self.name    
    def compute_pay(self):    
        daily = rate / 20    
        return rate - (daily*absent)  

class Payslip(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)  
    salary = models.IntegerField()    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## views.py

```
def compute(request):
    if request.method == "POST":  
        return render(request,'payroll/compute/compute.html')
```

Comment: It is highly appreciated if you can copy paste the code here instead of pictures.

Comment: Hi Faruk, i updated the post. Thank you. You may still view the photo to see what the page looks like..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is a need for another model Payslip, also you have no ForeignKey connections between the two models for it to work.

Considering your requirement, property decorator should work. Read up on how @property works. Basically, it acts as a pseudo model field, keep in mind the value of this field is not stored anywhere in the database, but it is tailor-made for situations like this where the field changes based on other fields and is needed for read-only.

Try this

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    rate = models.IntegerField()
    absent = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):    
        return self.name    

    @property
    def compute_pay(self):    
        daily = self.rate / 20    
        return (self.rate - (daily*self.absent))
```

you can get the employee's salary by Employee.compute_pay just like any other model field

Comment: Thank you Paritosh for pointing me to the right direction. Will follow ur advice. Thanks!!!

Comment: Hi Paritosh, I had an idea, I put the function in my view instead, is it okay to put the function here if i will have plenty of computations in my Payslip?
btw, the main purpose of this is to archive the payslip as well so i realized i cannot go with your recommendation.
https://imgur.com/a/rWg7c7I
This link above works for me, but I dont know how to iterate Employee model to do this to all of employee?